# Change the font from normal to bold using recyclerview position

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am working on my java code as I want to change the font from normal to bold when I click on the unread button in the toolbar in the mainactivity.

When I try this:

```
public void Unread(int position) {

    notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

It will not change the font from normal to bold in the recyclerview for the adapter.

Here is the code for Adapter:

```
public class InboxAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InboxAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public InboxAdapter adapter;
    public Fragment _fragment;
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // change the font style depending on message read status
        applyReadStatus(holder, inbox);

        holder.actionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#e8f0fd"));
                gd.setCornerRadius(40);
                gd.setStroke(40, Color.parseColor("#e8f0fd"));
                holder.layout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e8f0fd"));
                holder.layout1.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);*/
                int idx = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                String id = mInboxes.get(idx).getId();

                String short_name = holder.tvIcon.getText().toString();
                String subject1 = mInboxes.get(idx).getSubject();
                String from = mInboxes.get(idx).getFrom();
                String from_email = mInboxes.get(idx).getEmail();
                String datetime = mInboxes.get(idx).getDate();
                String isRead = mInboxes.get(idx).getRead();
                String isImportant = mInboxes.get(idx).isImportant();

                // set the read status
                setReadStatus(holder, isRead);

                openEmailActivity(mailbox, id, idx, color, short_name, subject1, from, from_email, datetime, isImportant);
               /* gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                gd.setCornerRadius(40);
                gd.setStroke(40, Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                holder.layout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                holder.layout1.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);*/
            }
        });
    }


    public void applyReadStatus(ViewHolder holder, inbox inbox) {
        if (inbox.getRead().equals("read")) {
            holder.from.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
            holder.subject.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
            holder.from.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.subject));
            holder.subject.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.message));
            holder.time.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.timestamp));
            holder.time.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        } else {
            holder.from.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.subject.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.from.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.from));
            holder.subject.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.subject));
            holder.time.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.timestamp));
            holder.time.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }
    }


    public void Unread(int position) {

        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }


public void openEmailActivity(String mailbox, String id, int idx, int color, String short_name, String subject1, String from, String from_email, String datetime, String isImportant) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity5.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("mailbox", mailbox);
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
        intent.putExtra("idx", idx);
        intent.putExtra("bg_color", color);
        intent.putExtra("short_name", short_name);
        intent.putExtra("subject", subject1);
        intent.putExtra("from_sender", from);
        intent.putExtra("from_email", from_email);
        intent.putExtra("datetime", datetime);
        intent.putExtra("is_important", isImportant);
        _fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity2.REQ_EMAIL_OPEN);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for InboxFragment:

```
public class InboxFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final int REQ_EMAIL_OPEN = 3456;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeLayout;
    private InboxAdapter mInboxAdapter;
    private List<inbox> mInbox = new ArrayList<>();
    private inbox Inbox;
    private Call<List<inbox>> call;
    private Window window;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private FloatingActionButton fab1;
    private String contacts = null;
    private String mailbox = null;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == REQ_EMAIL_OPEN){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data!= null){
                boolean isEmailDeleted = data.getBooleanExtra("isEmailDeleted",false);
                boolean isEmailUnread = data.getBooleanExtra("isEmailUnread",false);
                boolean isEmailRead = data.getBooleanExtra("isEmailRead",false);
                int emailId = data.getIntExtra("emailId",-1);

                if (isEmailDeleted && emailId != -1) {
                    mInboxAdapter.removeItem(emailId);
                }
                else if (isEmailUnread && emailId != -1) {
                    mInboxAdapter.Unread(emailId);
                }
                else if (isEmailRead && emailId != -1) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please show me an example how I can change the font from normal to bold for these textview of `from`, `subject` and `time`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are controlling the text style under this condition, `inbox.getRead().equals("read")`, but you are not actually changing the value of your `read` value in the inbox object.

What you should do is, you should change the value of `read` property of your `inbox` object at the particular position, and then call `notifyItemChanged(position);`.

You should do something like this,

```
public void Unread(int position) {
    this.list.get(position).setRead("unread");
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

This should change the `read` in your `inbox` object, and should work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for this as this is exactly what I am looking for. Problem are now resolved.

Comment: Glad this could help!